# How do I prevent Qt Creator from generating multiple .so files for the same library?

Tags: gcc, qmake

I am using Qt Creator to generate a library, and while it does work, it generates four versions of the file that, as far as I can tell, are identical to one another except that they are linked together.  The files are labeled as such: libFile.so, libFile.so.1, libFile.so.1.0, and libFile.so.1.0.0.  I only want to keep the libFile.so file.  How do I prevent the other files from being generated and being auto-linked together?

Answer (score 5):

qmake generates three targets for shared library configuration. One option to avoid creation of symbolic links is to set plugin configuration into your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += plugin
```

or you can put post-build script for removing of symbolic links in destdir folder.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one shared object, rest are just [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) s to it. This is how shared object naming works in Unix-like systems in order to support backwards-compatibility. Read more about [soname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) on Wikipedia.